# Is it possible to have singe log message for a variable, instead of spamming it in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, if I am for example checking what code is being run at which point and I use Debug.Log("message"); in the update function, it gets spammed every frame obviously.
Is there a way to have just a single log message that keeps changing values, instead of creating hundreds of new ones?

I am doing this sort of debugging a lot. For many variables, I have created UI components that show the current values, but it would be very helpful to have this just in the console.

Comment: There is a "Collapse" button on the console that collapses logs that are the same into one, and has a counter that shows how many times it's been logged, which might be what you want. But other than that, I'm not aware of a way to modify a previous log message.

Comment: @joll05 Collapsed console has a problem that it's still creating multiple log chains if you go to that Debug.Log call from different places (e.g. multiple scripts handle recoil and the log messages come from a script handling the recoil). This makes it difficult to track which one was the most recent etc.

Comment: That's not debugging. If you want to see values on variables, use the Locals or Autos windows in the VS Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this a bunch, it could be helpful to create a ScriptableObject that can hold the values of interest and display them in a custom Editor Window. Something like:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "StateSO", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/StateSO")]
public class StateSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Value1;
    public string Value2;
    // etc
}
```

With that in your app, go to Project Explorer, right-click a Resources folder (I use Assets/Resources/ScriptableObjects) -> Create -> ScriptableObjects -> StateSO

In your app scripts you add the member: `StateSO _stateSO;`

and in the Start(), connect the script to the ScriptableObject:

```
_stateSO = Resources.Load("ScriptableObjects/StateSO") as StateSO;
```

When Value1 changes:

```
_stateSO.Value1 = Value1;
```

Then you can create an Editor Window (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-EditorWindows.html) that in Init connects to that SO and in its OnGUI print those values out using EditorGUILayout.LabelField, something like this under Assets/Scripts/Editor/MyDebugger.cs:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyDebugger : EditorWindow
{
    StateSO _stateSO;
    
    [MenuItem("Examples/MyDebugger")]
    static void Init()
    {
        _stateSO = Resources.Load("ScriptableObjects/StateSO") as StateSO; // or whatever folder you created the SO in
        
        LabelFieldExample window = (LabelFieldExample)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(LabelFieldExample), true, "My Debugger");
        window.Show();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Value1: ", _stateSO.Value1);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Value2: ", _stateSO.Value2);
        this.Repaint();
    }
}
```